# I am trying to add zoom-out cursor on my image

Tags: css, scss-mixins

```
.zoom-overlay-open {
  overflow: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: zoom-out;
}

.img-responsive .zoom-img{
  cursor: -moz-zoom-out;
  cursor: -webkit-zoom-out;
  cursor: zoom-out !important;
}
```

im trying to add in zoom out icon along with pointer events none but it isnt working can you please help me out!

Comment: We can’t really help without seeing the related HTML.

Comment: I think instead of combining classes with a space, you should use .img-responsive.zoom-img to target elements with both classes. Can u try? And please share html also.